# Graceful way to handle multiple definitions

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I am using a 3rd party C library in a VStudio C++ project. The provider of the library is also a visual studio shop so I know this should be copacetic, but I can't figure out how to do it without editing their include files.

The problem is that 2 header files that have to be included everywhere have the same definitions:

```
#ifdef C_MICROSOFT

#define WRAPPER_FUNC  __declspec(dllexport)
#define STANDARD_FUNC
#define WRAPPER_CALL  _cdecl
#define STANDARD_CALL _stdcall
etc.. about 30 more
```

when I add those 2 headers to my project I get many errors such as:

```
C2086   'int STANDARD_FUNC': redefinition
```

I can however compile one of their example projects with the same headers included in the same order, without problems. I assume it's a compiler/language setting somewhere but I've been over the project properties with a fine tooth comb and I can't figure out what it is.

I know that I can either delete the duplicate definition or add another guard, but I'd rather not edit their files, as it will introduce a possible source of error every time the library gets updated.

Comment: Is there any `#ifdef` in the headers that could have an impact on these  definitions? Maybe you can play with when both headers are included. Maybe you could add the example project that works.

Comment: If multiple definitions of a macro are the same the code is valid. This looks like the result of one of those perverse compiler settings that treats warnings as errors, and gives warnings about everything under the sun.

Comment: @PeteBecker thanks for the confirmation that it should be ok. They aren't coming up as warnings, though, Visual Studio reports 220 errors and 0 warnings.